# Problems with canvas html5 can't close a draw

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

I'm developing a website where you can insert data of person, each person is represented by a image (a circle), the images are in a html table(the rows are the years and the columns are the months), depends of birth date, they will be in one position or other position.
Well the thing is that I have to link the images with canvas to make a figure, a close figure. And by now I only managed to join it with lines, I know that if you use the property  `".fill()"`  the figure will be closed, but it doesn't work and I don't know why.
What I'm doing wrong?

Here is my js code:
(I call the function "person" from the event **onClick()** in a button of the html, every time you insert a person)

```
    function position(year, mon) //this function puts the images
    {
        $('#' + year + ' .' + mon).prepend('<img class="black_point" src="./images/circle.png"/>');    
    }
    function person () {
        var date;
        date=prompt('Birthday date','01/01/1935');
        var elem = date.split('/'); 
        var month= elem[1]; //we take the month
        var year=elem[2]; //we take the year
        var mon= num2mon(month);
        var rw=document.getElementById("table").rows.length;
        var cols = $("#table").find('tr')[0].cells.length;
        position(year,mon);
     draw();
    }


    function draw() { //this function draw the lines
        var table = document.getElementById("table");
        var images = table.getElementsByTagName("img");  
        var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var x,y;

        canvas.width  = table.offsetWidth;
        canvas.height = table.offsetHeight;

          function connect(image) { //this function link the images
            var tabBcr = table.getBoundingClientRect();
            var imgBcr = image.getBoundingClientRect();
            ctx.beginPath();
            ctx.moveTo(x, y);

            x = imgBcr.left + (imgBcr.width / 2) - tabBcr.left;
            y = imgBcr.top + (imgBcr.height / 2) - tabBcr.top;

            ctx.lineTo(x, y);
            ctx.stroke();

            //ctx.fill(); //that's no work :S
            //ctx.closePath();

          }
        for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++){ 
          connect( images[i]);
        }
    }
```

Thank you!

Comment: The problem is that the colour is not filling?

Comment: No the problem is not close the figure and not filled

Comment: Well from what I see, you're not using ctx.fillStyle which is what the colour will be when filling lines, so I assume you've drawn a white background and you're trying to fill it with a white background

Comment: @JessicaPartridge default fillStyle is solid black. Default canvas background is transparent black (not visible).

Comment: Yeah but the problem was that i can't close the figure

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two kind of paths in canvas, the main path and then sub-paths.

For a close to work you need to only have max one sub-path. Every time moveTo() is used a new sub-path will be created so when a line is made like this:

```
moveTo(x1, y1);
lineTo(x2, y2);
moveTo(x2, y2);
lineTo(x3, y3);
```

You have two sub-paths that are not connected. What you want is to continue adding lines to the existing sub-paths like this:

```
moveTo(x1, y1);
lineTo(x2, y2);
lineTo(x3, y3);
```

Now it is possible to close the shape connecting x3->x1 and y3->y1.

Using `ctx.beginPath()` in this case makes it worst. It will clear *all* sub-paths added to the main path.

What you need to do is to globally (or at some higher level) create a new path using `beginPath()` (every time you need to redraw the content for example).

Then the first line needs to be set using `moveTo()`. Then every other lines using `lineTo()`.

Finally you can use `closePath()` and render it using `stroke()` or `fill()` (closePath() is not needed with fill, with stroke it must be called *before* stroke).

**For example** (untested, adopt as needed):

```
function draw() { //this function draw the lines
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    var images = table.getElementsByTagName("img");  
    var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var x,y;

    canvas.width  = table.offsetWidth;
    canvas.height = table.offsetHeight;

    function connect(image, index) { //this function link the images
        var tabBcr = table.getBoundingClientRect();
        var imgBcr = image.getBoundingClientRect();

        x = imgBcr.left + (imgBcr.width / 2) - tabBcr.left;
        y = imgBcr.top + (imgBcr.height / 2) - tabBcr.top;

        index === 0 ? ctx.moveTo(x, y) : ctx.lineTo(x, y);
    }

    // new path here
    ctx.beginPath();

    for(var i=0; i<images.length; i++){ 
      connect( images[i], i);  // provide index so we can sep. move/line
    }

    // then at the end:
    ctx.fill();
}
```

Comment: @AliATriple no beginPath() first (this clears the path). Then moveTo to start a new sub-path on the newly cleared path, then add lines. If not the first line will be drawn from (0,0).

Comment: I understand it wrong okay okay, so `moveTo()`is the property who start the path, i think was the other. thanks, and yes that's work.